# В чем причина ошибок

Tags: php

По [этой ссылке](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=37&id=350) учился делать регистрацию, но в 5 пункте (изменение файла index) заметил появления 4-х ошибок 36, 84, 89, 90 строчки, пробовал исправить сам - ничего не получается, помогите исправить или скажите, что я делаю не так!

Comment: Ну, вы бы строки привели, где ошибка и сами ошибки.

Comment: Совет : на сайте ibm.com есть хорошие статьи, читайте их, чем те, которые друг у друга копированные на левых сайтах, которые пишут не особо одарённые люди.
А код желательно показать, ибо инструмента нет под рукой.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вначале внимательно читаем [тут](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc).

Если после этого исправить не получится, то ищем в тексте index.php строки "HERE;" В некоторых местах они предваряемые кучей пробелов. А это нарушение синтаксиса. Слово "HERE;" должно быть в самом начале строки (в тексте есть один случай, где это написано правильно, он самый последний).
а потом снова читаем статью по ссылки, до полного понимания, что такое heredoc синтаксис. Либо гуглим по словам "php heredoc"